# How to fix VS Code PHP IntelliSense HTML formatting?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Felix Becker [PHP IntelliSense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense) for VS Code.

When getting function parameter descriptions, the descriptions are not formatted properly. They show up with HTML tags.

Is there any way to fix this, so the descriptions are formatted properly?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it seems this is currently not possible. There is a pending VSCode feature request for this (created by the author of the PHP extension you linked):

[HTML inside hover/signature help markdown is not rendered (#40607)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40607)